# Show that $(1+z)\Pi^{\infty}(1+z^{2^{n}})=\frac{1}{1-z}$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}$ $|z|<1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product

$(1+z)\Pi^{\infty}(1+z^{2^{n}})=\frac{1}{1-z}$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}$ $|z|<1$.

Any tricks to prove this?  I'm not really sure how to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the partial products.  You should be able to prove by induction that
$$\prod_{k=0}^n(1+z^{2^k})=\sum_{k=0}^{2^{n+1}-1}z^k.$$

Comment: Yes. Absolutely.  I'll fix it.

Comment: That was perfect!